# Indexing an array by a quotient

Tags: javascript, rounding-error, rounding

In the following code, `i` will always be an even number so the quotient `i / 2` should always be an integer. Should I still use `Math.floor(i / 2)` to be on the safe side? I'm asking because JavaScript does treat all numbers as floating points so I'm concerned about rounding errors.

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i = i + 2) {
    var name = names[i / 2];
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [JavaScript(ECMAScript<sup>®</sup>) Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/) if

```
i <= Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER + 1
```

then `i` can be exactly represented and the division should work out fine.

> The value of [`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-number.max_safe_integer) is the largest integer n such that n and n + 1 are both exactly representable as a Number value.
>
> The value of [`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-number.max_safe_integer) is 9007199254740991 (2<sup>53</sup>−1).

**[Section 12.7.3.2 Applying the / Operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-applying-the-div-operator)**

> In the remaining cases, where neither an infinity, nor a zero, nor NaN is involved, the quotient is computed and rounded to the nearest representable value using IEEE 754-2008 round to nearest, ties to even mode. If the magnitude is too large to represent, the operation overflows; the result is then an infinity of appropriate sign. If the magnitude is too small to represent, the operation underflows and the result is a zero of the appropriate sign. The ECMAScript language requires support of gradual underflow as defined by IEEE 754-2008.

Answer (score 3):

No. you do not have to use `Math.floor()` in this situation.

Because `i` is always even and also `names[1.00]` is equivalent to `names[1]`.

To check, try the below in a javascript console.

The length of array will be 20 and the first 10 array items will be printed

```js
var names = ["nums1", "nums2", "nums3","nums4", "nums5", "nums6","nums7", 
    "nums8", "nums9","nums10", "nums11","nums12", "nums13","nums14", "nums15", 
    "nums16","nums17", "nums18", "nums19","nums20"];

for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i = i + 2) {
    console.log(names[i/2]);
}
```

Comment: I understand that it works in this particular example, but how do you know that there is not some platform where `i/2` will return `1.00000002` and give an error if I try indexing by that?

Comment: If i is starting at zero and increasing by 2 every iteration, I do not see why i/2 would return any value but a whole number.                                                Can you state any example of any platform that you know of that does that.

Answer (score 2):

Dividing even integers by 2 always returns an integer as long as it does not overflow

```
Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER
```

after that, integers are stored with a power of two, so they lose precision.
However arrays which are bigger than this size would have problems accessing their elements (as indexes get imprecise), the maximum number of elements you can push into an array is limited to exactly this maximum safe integer. So basically your code will always work, if it doesn't, that's because the array overflows and not because the index is wrong. However, I rather recommend you to do:

```js
  var array = ["one", "two", "three","four", "five", "six","seven", 
    "eight", "nine","ten", "eleven","twelve", "thirteen","fourteen", "fifteen", 
    "sixteen","seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen","twenty"];
    
  for(var i=0,l=array.length/2;i<l;i++){
      console.log(array[i]);
    }
```

As it saves these unnecessary math operations...

Comment: Can you provide a link to documentation substantiating your claim? Thanks

Comment: @roland *In the remaining cases, where neither an infinity, nor a zero, nor NaN is involved, the quotient is computed and rounded to the nearest representable value using IEEE 754-2008 round-to-nearest mode. If the magnitude is too large to represent, the operation overflows; the result is then an infinity of appropriate sign. If the magnitude is too small to represent, the operation underflows and the result is a zero of the appropriate sign. The ECMAScript language requires support of gradual underflow as defined by IEEE 754-2008.*

Comment: Link to relevant section in the [JavaScript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-applying-the-div-operator)